# Any bad impact of imbalanced data in deep learning?

Tags: image-recognition

I found that in popular data sets like imagenet, cifar-100, the number of images for each categories are the same.
I wonder if there is any bad impact if the training images for classification is imbalanced. (e.g. 100 for leopards while 5000 for elephants)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could have some problems in this case: the hidden layers will train more toward features of elephants.  If you increase the number of hidden filters or neurons to accommodate the leopards, you risk over-fitting elephants in the process.

The main issue is whether you have sufficient leopard images to differentiate them from the rest of the input.  If so, and if you load the training data such that the leopards comprise a good balance in the first 200-300 photos trained, then the latter training for elephants will have a lesser impact on the features "discovered".  However, this affects training speed more than accuracy.